# Angular + Spring + wso2 - Authorization Code Flow + PKCE

Tags: angular, wso2, authorization, wso2-identity-server, angular-oauth2-oidc

My application has a login page that contains only a button that redirects to the WSO2 Identity Server Authorization Server.

This redirect is done by the library angular-oauth2-oidc.

Then I have a backend that calls WSO2 SCIM2.O api's.

In my OAuthConfig i specify only the clientId (because i know that the client secret should never be in the front-end) and I've noticied that the library automatically uses the Authorization code with PKCE because in the url it add the parameter code_challenge, and I'm fine with it since i read that this type of flow is good when you don't want to use the client secret.

When I insert my credentials, I'm redirect to the url that I specified in the redirect_uri of the OAuthConfig, then i click on a button to add a new item and this event calls my backend api (which calls the wso2 scim api). And it doesn't work.

But if i specify in the OAuthConfig the clientID AND the clientSecret, then it works.

And i don't understand why since I'm using the flow with PKCE.  I'm guessing that the problem is with the access token that gets generated? Is there any step I'm missing?

Comment: If the clientSecret value is not given in OAuthConfig, what is the response you get for the SCIM API request?

Comment: What is the IS version you are using? If it is 6.0, you need to mark that  app as a `Management App` in IS https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/#oauth-based-authentication?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without a way to minimally reproduce your situation. I know it's been some time since you asked the question, but I think we need some code that illustrates the issue. (As a general hint, you could [clone my sample repo](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards) and reconfigure it to use your own IDP to see if that works.)